# Rails Ready script doesn't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have just installed [Rails Ready script from GitHub](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready) on my Ubuntu Server 10.04.
Installation was ok:

```
Using aptitude for package installation
=> Updating system (this may take awhile)...
==> done...
=> Installing build tools...
==> done..
=> Installing libs needed for sqlite and mysql...
==> done...
=> Installing imagemagick (this may take awhile)...
==> done...
=> Installing git...
==> done...
==> done running ubuntu specific commands...
=> Installing RVM the Ruby enVironment Manager http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ 
=> Setting up RVM to load with new shells...
==> done...
=> Loading RVM...
==> done...
=> Installing Ruby 1.9.2p136 (this will take awhile)...
=> More information about installing rubies can be found at http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/installing/ 
==> done...
=> Using 1.9.2 and setting it as default for new shells...
=> More information about Rubies can be found at http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/
==> done...
=> Reloading shell so ruby and rubygems are available...
==> done...
=> Installing Bundler, Passenger and Rails..
==> done...
#################################
### Installation is complete! ###
#################################
 !!! logout and back in to access Ruby or run source ~/.bashrc !!!
 Thanks!
-Josh
```

After installation, I logged out and return to shell.

Then, howewer, I can't execute any Rails-related command:

```
user@9001-3:~$ ruby
-bash: ruby: command not found
user@9001-3:~$ rails
-bash: rails: command not found
user@9001-3:~$ rvm
-bash: rvm: command not found
user@9001-3:~$ passenger-install-apache-module
-bash: passenger-install-apache-module: command not found
```

~/.bashrc also doesn't works!

```
user@9001-3:~$ sudo bash ~/.bashrc
/home/user/.bashrc: line 6: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script

$rvm_path (/usr/local/rvm) does not exist.
$rvm_path (/usr/local/rvm) does not exist.user@9001-3:~$
```

The bashrc can be read here : http://pastebin.com/6K541E2V

Please, can you help me?

Comment: user@9001-3:~$ rvm list
-bash: rvm: command not found

Comment: here, please: http://pastebin.com/6K541E2V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you .bashrc failed to be load completly.

Copy the last line from it :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

To in first line of you .bashrc. After I suppose it's works.

Reinstall rvm :

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it right: you should include path to Ruby to PATH environment varable.

Why ~/.bashrc doesn't work (with solution) described, for example, here:  http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=215490

Answer (score 0):

all I had to do was type in

```
source ~/.bashrc
```